# Get record with Max value from SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I am trying to `get max value` of a column in my query but I cant found any solution. My query is

```
SELECT pz.id, 
    sz.Price + cr.AddedCost AS price
FROM piz pz, crust cr, size sz
WHERE 
    pz.SizeID = sz.id AND
    pz.CrustID = tp.id
```

Then I receive some records like the following

```
ID  price
-----------
1   95000.0
6   160000.0
10  150000.0
3   137500.0
5   122500.0
4   195000.0
2   195000.0
7   130000.0
8   205000.0
9   130000.0
11  205000.0
```

I want to get the `record` with the `max value` of price, which are:

```
ID  price
------------
8   205000.0
11  205000.0
```

I am using Navicat with MySQL server

Update:
I did try using:

```
SELECT pz.id, MAX(sz.Price + cr.AddedCost) AS price ....
```

But it didnt work as the returned id is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you do this.

Change all your old style comma separated join to Inner join for better readability.

```
SELECT pz.id,
       sz.Price + cr.AddedCost AS price
FROM   piz pz
       INNER JOIN crust cr
               ON pz.CrustID = cr.id
       INNER JOIN size sz
               ON pz.SizeID = sz.id
WHERE  sz.Price + cr.AddedCost = (SELECT sz.Price + cr.AddedCost AS price
                                   FROM   piz pz1
                                          INNER JOIN crust cr1
                                                  ON pz1.CrustID = cr1.id
                                          INNER JOIN size sz1
                                                  ON pz1.SizeID = sz1.id
                                   ORDER  BY price DESC limit 1 )
```

Comment: Thank you! it works. However, do you think that there is any other methods that we do not need to execute the query two times like in this case?

Comment: @PhucTran - yeah even i thought about it. But am not good in `Mysql`. In Sql Server it is very simple to get this solution using `Top 1 with ties`. Try searching the alternative in `Mysql`

Comment: `Top 1 with ties` seems not to fit in this case as the result can be 1, 2 or more records while `top 1 with ties` returns 1 record as I know

Comment: @PhucTran - Nope its not like that. It will return all the rows with ties. Result can be more than one.

Comment: I found a link and it says that `The SELECT TOP N query always return exactly N records, and arbitrarily drops any record that have the same value as the last record in the group`. In this case, I dont know exactly how many rows will be returned before executing.
http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18477

Answer (score 1):

use Max function :) select MAX(column) from ...

Comment: When I use `SELECT pz.id, MAX(sz.Price + cr.AddedCost) AS price`. It returns the right price but the wrong id

Comment: try SELECT pz.id ,sz.Price + cr.AddedCostAS AS price FROM table WHERE price = MAX(sz.Price + cr.AddedCost)

Answer (score 0):

select MAX(col) from where 
but note that this col must be number not string

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT pz.id, 
        sz.Price + cr.AddedCost AS price
    FROM piz pz, crust cr, size sz,
    (
    select max(sz.Price + cr.AddedCost) as v 
    from crust cr, size sz
    where pz.SizeID = sz.id
    and pz.CrustID = tp.id
    )t
    WHERE 
        pz.SizeID = sz.id AND
        pz.CrustID = tp.id AND 
        (sz.Price + cr.AddedCost) = t.v
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT pz.id, 
sz.Price + cr.AddedCost AS price
FROM piz pz, crust cr, size sz
WHERE 
pz.SizeID = sz.id AND
pz.CrustID = tp.id
HAVING
price = (SELECT max(sz.Price + cr.AddedCost) from crust cr, size sz)
```